# How does Moq verify Generic Func Parameter?

Tags: c#, moq

Given

```
public interface IService
{
  void Run<T>(T value, Func<T, string> func);
}

public class Sut
{
  private readonly IService m_service;

    public Sut(IService service)
    {
        m_service = service;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Point point = new Point {X = 1, Y = 2};
        m_service.Run(point, p => $"X:{p.X}, Y:{p.Y}");
    }
}

internal class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And tested like

```
[Test]
public void RunTest()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IService> mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    var sut = new Sut(mockService.Object);

    // Act
    sut.Test();

    // Assert
    mockService.Verify(e => e.Run(It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, string>>()), Times.Once);
}
```

This test will failed, due to Point is third party internal class, I can not use `It.IsAny<Point>` in the verify.

if I change the Point to the public and verify use following, it's working good.

```
mockService.Verify(e => e.Run(It.IsAny<Point>(), It.IsAny<Func<Point, string>>()), Times.Once);
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to put an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in the assembly under test, pointing to the test assembly.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) for reference information.

Comment: the point class is a third-party assembly, I can not add this, thanks

Comment: If it's a third parties how are you using it in your code? You should not test a library.

Comment: the  IService and Point is from third party dll, but the Sut is in my project, the test is testing for Sut, not for IService.

Comment: How can SUT use Point if it's an internal type of a third assembly?? Your example code is wrong, I think.

Comment: original code use extension methods hide the Point class. 
I just make a simple version of it. something like this
public static class ServiceExtension
    {
        public static void Run(this IService service)
        {
            Point point = new Point {X = 1, Y = 2};
            service.Run(point, p => $"X:{p.X}, Y:{p.Y}");
        }
    }

Comment: Your problem is not about Moq, I think. Your problem is about internal classes unavailable to tests. You should describe exactly _that_ part. Or, for this specific case, get rid of Moq and check the parameter type as an object looking at parameter.GetType().Name

Comment: Maybe there's a bug on Moq to check the Func parameter use It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, string>>()